# Google Drive SDK iOS9

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm having trouble building my project against the Drive SDK for iOS9. It has mostly to do with a lot of methods being deprecated and certain header files not being found. Any tips on how to make the SDK work with iOS9? Also, will the SDK be updated for iOS9 anytime soon?

Comment: You will need to tell us what headers are not found and give more details, otherwise we won't be able to help.

Comment: `GTMSessionFetcher.h' file not found`
This is what I'm getting currently. Also I'm getting a lot of warnings about depreciated methods for iOS9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I seem to have got it working by using https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client via Cocoapods. That solved all the issues I had.

Comment: Just for people coming by full instructions would be to go to this page https://cocoapods.org/pods/Google-API-Client and add the right entry to your Podfile. If you don't know how to use cocoapods then google how to do that. For me it was  pod 'Google-API-Client', '~> 1.0.422'

Answer (score 0):

There is some refactoring that needs to be done to assure compatibility.
Unfortunately, this is due to some incomplete transitions of the library, 
including the move to support iOS 9 and OS X 10.11, which have deprecated 
NSURLConnection.

For now, if your project targets iOS 8 or OS X 10.10 or earlier, then define 
GTM_USE_SESSION_FETCHER to 0 for your targets. That will force the library to 
use the old GTMHTTPFetcher class.

If your minimum target is iOS 9 or OS X 10.11, you'll instead need to replace 
GTMHTTPFetcher with GTMSessionFetcher from 
https://code.google.com/p/gtm-session-fetcher/

Hopefully this would work!

Comment: I'm building for iOS 8 and above, so I define to 0. However, now I get `/Source/HTTPFetcher/GTMGatherInputStream.m:21:11: Multiple methods named 'initWithArray:' found`